# How to do a Stacked Barplot for each Year per Region to calculate the sum(or average) of Quantity_Sold? Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I am not sure where to start, I am trying to get a graph that looks like shown below:

[image]

The y_axis represents the sum of Quantity sold per Year and per Region as shown on the graph

This **dataset** can be used:

```
dataset = {'Year': [2019,2020,2020,2019,2019,2020,2017,2017,2018,2020,2018,2016],
           'Quantity': [100,50,25,30,40,50,200,600,20,40,100,20],
           'Regions': ['Europe','Asia','Africa','Africa','Other','Asia','Africa','Other','America','America','Europe','Europe']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)
```

Also I am not sure if it's better to use matplotlib or seaborn in that case.

What I tried, ut it doesn't seem to be working:

```
dfc_vol = dfc[['Year','Quantity','Regions']]
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(10,6)
dfc_vol.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1,0.5))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps one option using `pivot_table` to reshape the data first:

```
df_pt = df.pivot_table(index='Year', columns='Regions', values='Quantity')

df_pt.plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(10, 6))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but for some reason it doesn't work with my data, the ```pivot_table``` compiles each regions more than once. So the plot doesn't look like anything

Comment: @KilliMandjaro can you provide an actual dataset then? I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: I fixed the pivot problem by adding ```values = Quantity``` but I get an error with the second line (drop). Can you explain what it does and why you added that?

Comment: @KilliMandjaro - actually `values = 'Quantity'` is a better approach here, edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

With seaborn >= 0.11.0:

```
sns.histplot(
    data=df,
    x="Year", hue="Regions", weights="Quantity",
    multiple="stack", discrete=True, shrink=.9
)
```

[image]

Comment: When I try to change the location of the legend with ```plt.legend()``` I have a message saying "no handles to put in legend". Do you know how to fix that? Plus if I want to change the order using ```hue_order``` what should I input? When I put a specific column name i.e. ```hue_order='Regions' ```.it doesn't work